# How can I specify data structure name from the string output in r programming?

Tags: r

I am coding this in r and solved this in an alternative way to make the vector to a list and assign value to each of the element of the list, but is there any other direct simple approach?

```
for(i in 1:5){
paste('var',i,sep='')=i
}
```

i want output where 1:5 will assign like

```
var1=1
var2=2
var3=3
var4=4
var5=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t do this. Use a vector or list instead:

```
var = 1 : 5
```

Now you can use `var[1]` (instead of `var1`) etc.

Your code doesn’t work because `paste` creates a *character vector*, not a variable name.

Comment: Are you going to open the `assign` can of worms to show how it could (but shouldn't) be done?

Comment: @Allen No, I’ve intentionally not done this. It’s virtually never the correct solution (outside of judicious metaprogramming), and it only confuses beginners.